# asp:linkbutton (navigating to specific page section on post back)

Tags: asp.net

I have some linkbuttons to update my gridview which is in the middle of the page. Everytime I hit edit or delete etc the window scrolls to the top on the page that gets posted back. I want it to stay focused on the grideview. I have tried a javascript function but for some reason it did not work.

(edit: the following works as far as scrolling is concerned but prevents postback)

here is what I tried

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  

    function goto()   {   

         window.scrollTo(10, 1100);   

    }   

</script>

<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnGo" runat="server"   OnClientClick="javascript:goto();return false;">GO</asp:LinkButton>
```

[source](http://forums.asp.net/p/441243/3647829.aspx)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try with `<%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>` in the page declaration?

Regards

Comment: this seems to work but I now my browser is showing a popup "stack overflow at line 0" everytime I click a link. The rest of the code in the page is not mine so some other function might be moving it up? I just noticed it doesnt go all the way to the top on postback.

Comment: Hummm, strange, maybe you could see in the forums http://forums.asp.net/t/1536471.aspx and http://forums.asp.net/t/1373552.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Client-side event fires before server-side. So even if you scroll window to correct position - after postback you will be returned to the top. You can add the following code to your server-side LinkButton click event handler:

```
  if (!this.IsStartupScriptRegistered("ScrollToGrid"))
    {
      String scriptString = "<script language=\"JavaScript\">";
      scriptString += "window.scrollTo(10, 1100);";
      scriptString += "</script>";
      this.RegisterStartupScript("ScrollToGrid", scriptString);
    }
```

this will add javascript block to your page after postback

Comment: and I link the function to linkbutton the same way?
OnClientClick="javascript:goto();return false;

because this does not seem to work so I must have missed something. How do I call the function after it has been registered after postback

Answer (score 0):

There are, depending on the .NET framework properties available that can help one out:

ASP.NET 1.x: use SmartNavigation. ASP.NET 2.0: use MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack. Use an UpdatePanel control to asynchronously update parts of a page

and the best way for this is UpdatePanel control to asynchronously update parts of a page